# Install Numpy Python Error Unable to find vcvarsall.bat but I do have it

Tags: python, numpy

It says it's unable to find `"vcvarsall.bat"` However, I did a search for it on my computer and I do have the file. I have Microsoft Visual Studios 2008. Does anyone know how can I make the distutils detect this file? I'm tryin to use this module with my PyCharm compiler. Thanks

Errors:

> No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils;
>   trying from distutils error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Comment: You are on Windows. I don't know the reason why it is happening. But use [This numpy module from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) will solve the problem hopefully.

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia official guide of Scipy stack giving links to unofficial windows binaries by Christoph Gohlke, Lol. :) Anyway still I don't know why this error. Hopefully someone can clear.

Comment: In short not all vcvarsall.bat files are the same. It depends on what version of VS was used to compile your Python installation and that depends on the version of Python you're using. IIRC Python 2.7 uses VC2008 for example while Python 3.x uses newer versions. You need to make sure you've installed the correct version of vcvarsall.bat for your Python distro (you can't just move the file I don't think). But really I'd suggest using Gohlke's Windows binaries.

Comment: @Ffisegydd Ah ok cool. Thanks. Yea I am using Visual Studios 2008. But, I read somewhere that Python 3.3+ is based of Visual Studios 2010. I am using Python 3.3.2 ... is it ok to have like Visual Studios 2008 and like Visual Studios 2010 Express on the same computer or will there be some kind of conflict?

Comment: I don't think there will be a conflict but not 100% sure, they should go in different directories so should be fine.